# Getting the smallest vector of two more efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization, vector

I want to find the smalles vector out of two given vectors.
I want to use `numpy` in `Python3`.
All I came up with is kind of inefficient due to unneccassary reshaping a array.
Is there a more efficient or at least a more elegant way than my own solution?

My way to find the smallest vector:
Input are some sort structs with 2 different vectors stored inside this struct.

```
def find_smallest(construct1, construct2):
    a = np.append(construct1.lower, construct2.lower)
    b = np.reshape(a, (-1,2))
    c = np.amin(b, axis=0)
    return c
```

The input is:

```
a = Construct(lower = [0,0], upper = [1,1])
b = Construct(lower = [1,1], upper = [11,11])
find_smallest(a, b)
```

The output I expect:

```
[0 0]
```

This is what the `Construct`-Class looks like:

```py
class Construct:

  def __init__(self, lower = [], upper, = []):
    self.__lower = np.array(lower)
    self.__upper = np.array(upper)

  @property
  def lower(self):
     return self.__lower

  @property
  def upper(self):
    return self.__upper
```

Comment: What is your definition for smallest vector? Is it their distance from origin `(0, 0)` ?

Comment: @SayandipDutta smallest in sense of smaller magnitude of the vector from the origin `(0, 0)` yes. And I mean the smaller one of both of them. So if you want: I want to find the "smaller" vector (in magnitude) by comparing them. If that makes sense.

Comment: For the usual L2 norm, you could use `np.linalg.norm`; other common vector space norms are available in `scipy`.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem true, but I think performancewise this would be overkill in my opinion. As in my approach you can see it would be enough by comparing all values in every axis to find the lowest which should be significantly faster then calculating the magnitude first an then compare it. So long with my thought to this.

Comment: It is hard to comment more without seeing the definition of the `Construct` class.

Comment: @Jedeiko What if you are comparing `[0,1]` with `[2,0]`? Your function will yield `[0,0]` as result.